# DATE in joined query echoing wrong characters

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a large query pulling data from several table.  My delivery date is echoing the wrong characters.  Here's my code along with an image of what its returning.  Below this code is a query from a single table and the Date looks fine.  Any ideas on how I can fix this.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$query = $connect->prepare("(SELECT 
jobs.jobID,
jobs.jobName,
jobs.pdfMolding,
jobs.statusOrder,
jobs.deliveryDate,

jobstatus.status,
jobstatus.statusOrder,

rooms.roomID, 
rooms.roomName, 
rooms.sprayDungeonS,
rooms.sprayDungeonF,
rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded,
rooms.woodType,
rooms.finishType,
rooms.finishColor,
rooms.isRush,
rooms.description,
jobnotes.note,

rushready.sprayDungeon,

startfinishcheck.sprayDungeonSE,
startfinishcheck.sprayDungeonFE
FROM jobs 
LEFT JOIN rooms ON jobs.jobID = rooms.jobID 
LEFT JOIN jobnotes ON jobnotes.jobID = jobs.jobID
LEFT JOIN jobstatus ON jobstatus.statusOrder = jobs.statusOrder
LEFT JOIN rushready ON rushready.roomID = rooms.roomID
LEFT JOIN startfinishcheck ON startfinishcheck.roomID = rooms.roomID
WHERE rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded = 1 AND rooms.isRush = 1 AND sprayDungeonF = 0 AND rushready.sprayDungeon = 1
OR rooms.isRush = 1 AND sprayDungeonF IS NULL AND rushready.sprayDungeon = 1 AND rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded = 1
GROUP BY rooms.roomID
ORDER BY deliveryDate LIMIT 50)

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
jobs.jobID,
jobs.jobName,
jobs.pdfMolding,
jobs.statusOrder,
jobs.deliveryDate,

jobstatus.status,
jobstatus.statusOrder,

rooms.roomID, 
rooms.roomName, 
rooms.sprayDungeonS,
rooms.sprayDungeonF,
rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded,
rooms.woodType,
rooms.finishType,
rooms.finishColor,
rooms.isRush,
rooms.description,
jobnotes.note,
rushready.sprayDungeon,
startfinishcheck.sprayDungeonSE,
startfinishcheck.sprayDungeonFE
FROM jobs 
LEFT JOIN rooms ON jobs.jobID = rooms.jobID 
LEFT JOIN jobnotes ON jobnotes.jobID = jobs.jobID
LEFT JOIN jobstatus ON jobstatus.statusOrder = jobs.statusOrder
LEFT JOIN rushready ON rushready.roomID = rooms.roomID
LEFT JOIN startfinishcheck ON startfinishcheck.roomID = rooms.roomID
WHERE ((rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded = 1 AND jobstatus.statusOrder >= 0 AND rooms.sprayDungeonF IS NULL)
OR (rooms.sprayDungeonNeeded = 1 AND jobstatus.statusOrder >= 0 AND rooms.sprayDungeonF = 0))
AND ((rooms.isRush = 0 AND rooms.sprayDungeonF = 0) OR (rooms.isRush = 0 AND rooms.sprayDungeonF IS NULL))
GROUP BY jobs.jobName, rooms.woodType, rooms.finishColor 
ORDER BY jobs.statusOrder = 7 DESC, deliveryDate, jobName, finishType LIMIT 50)");

if(!$query) {
    echo("Query Failed Because " . mysqli_error($connect));
};

$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jobID = $row['jobID'];
    $test = $row['deliveryDate'];
    echo $jobID . "-" . $test . "<br>";
}
```

[image]

And here's a simplified query where everything returns correctly

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT jobID, deliveryDate FROM jobs WHERE statusOrder > -1");
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a [UTP-8 All the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) issue to me

Comment: I tried adding mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8'); Still comes out that way